# Does Eigen Matrix support indexing by a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen

For example if I have a 4 by 4 matrix. Is there a way to create another matrix (or a view into original matrix, even better), that is only rows 1 and 3 of original matrix.

I only see how to extract a row, or a block, but no what I mentioned above. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  Matrix4f m = Matrix4f::Random();
  std::cout << "Matrix : " << std::endl;
  std::cout << m << std::endl;

  std::cout << "row" << std::endl;
  std::cout << m.row(1) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "block : " << std::endl;
  std::cout << m.block(1,0,2,4) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

A potential solution is to pre-multiply my matrix by a matrix of ones and zeros,

```
 z = ([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

z * m would give me what I want, but is there a better solution.

Edit:

A possible application of what I want to do:

Let's say I have matrices `A(m x n)` and `B(n x k)`. I want to sample from `A` and multiply by `B`, say I take `1/5th` of A's rows `A'(m/5 X n) * B(n x k)` is what I am after. I don't need `A'` itself, it is that product that I am after.

Comment: Well to create another matrix with only rows 1 and 3 can't you just *get rows 1 and 3* and *put them in a new 2x4 matrix*?

Comment: @Jashaszun, thanks. How efficient would that solution be?

Comment: Probably pretty efficient, as you're only using 8 numbers for the two rows (4 numbers per row).

Comment: In practice my matrix is much larger, and maybe I'll need to use the solution you suggested, but I also want to make sure that there is no convenient built-in method for something like this exists.

Comment: Oh ok. If the matrices are bigger, then I don't know the efficiency. (I've never even used `eigen` before, so I don't really know what I'm talking about here. Sorry!)

Comment: Probably you can use [Map](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) and [Stride](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Stride.html). Can you give example of the actual operations you want to do with that new matrix. If it just printing, simply using m.row(1) and m.row(3) should be good enough.

Comment: @iNFINITEi, Thank You these look promising. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

Eigen's permutation matrix might be what you're looking for:

[Randomly permute rows/columns of a matrix with eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858569/randomly-permute-rows-columns-of-a-matrix-with-eigen)

```
using Eigen;
Matrix4f m = Matrix4f::Random();

PermutationMatrix<Dynamic,Dynamic> P(4);
perm.indices()[0] = 1;
perm.indices()[1] = 3;

MatrixXf B = (m * P).leftCols(2);
```

Comment: Please explain a little more. A link should serve as an aid to an answer rather than be the answer itself.