# Permute Columns of Matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen3

I read this answer [Randomly permute rows/columns of a matrix with eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858569/randomly-permute-rows-columns-of-a-matrix-with-eigen)

But they initialize the permutation matrix as the identity matrix and do a random shuffle. I'm wondering how I can initialize the matrix to a specific permutation.

For example, if I have a vector of integers where each (index, value) pair means I want to move column "index" to column "value" how can I do this?

```
Eigen::MatrixXi M = Eigen::MatrixXi::Random(3,3);
std::vector<int> my_perm = {1,2,0};
some_function to return Matrix [M.col(1), M.col(2), M.col(0)]
```

**EDIT: dtell kindly answered my original question below.**

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

For anyone else looking at this -- if you want to permute a matrix with a vector of unknown (at compile time) quanties, you can do the following:

```
Eigen::VectorXi indices(A.cols());
for(long i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
    indices[i] = vector_of_indices[i];
}
Eigen::PermutationMatrix<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> perm;
perm.indices() = indices;
Eigen::MatrixXd A_permute = A * perm; \\ permute the columns
```

Comment: Please double-check your example. If you actually want to return the columns in order then I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: Also, have you actually looked at the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PermutationMatrix.html#a204b8bbba3c4d33c1a24bb60ad72b202)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the answer to your question is this slight modification of the answer you have linked

```
Matrix3i A = Matrix3i::Random();
PermutationMatrix<3, 3> perm;
// Your permutation
perm.indices() = { 1, 2, 0 };
// Permutate rows
A = perm * A;
```